# Aestan Tray Error-yesterday working properly my wamp server. but now i got this error

Tags: wamp

Aestan Tray Error-the configeration file contains a syntax error on line 0;[EParseError]no tray icon was spesified. please assign a tray icon by using one of the trayicon* detectives in the [config]section . yesterday working properly my wamp server. but now i got this error

how to solve this problem?